# Take photo just pressing the shutter release

Tags: c#, xamarin

I need some advice on how to use the camera in Xamarin.Forms.
Currently, NuGet Xam.Plugin.Media.
Media. With the following code, when you press a button from the UI, the camera starts up, takes a picture and displays the image on the screen.

````
    private async void OnCameraTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var photo = await CaptureCamera();
        Image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream() =>
        {
            return new MemoryStream(photo);
        });
    }
    ```
    
    ```
    private async Task<byte[]> CaptureCamera()
    {
        await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current. Initialize();
    
        Initialize(); if (!Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current. IsCameraAvailable ||
    !Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current. IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            return null;
        }
    
        var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia. CrossMedia.
    .TakePhotoAsync(
    new Plugin.Media.Abstractions. StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Directory = "Photo",
            Name = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MMdd_HHHmm ") + "Photo.jpg",
        });
    
        if (file == null)
            return null;
    
        var bytes = new Queue<byte>();
        using (var s = file.GetStream())
        {
            var length = s.Length;
            int b;
            while ((b = s.ReadByte()) ! = -1)
                bytes.Enqueue((byte)b);
        }
        Dispose();
        Dispose(); if (bytes == null) return null;
        return bytes.ToArray();
    }
````

However, this method uses Plugin.Media.CrossMedia, which means that the There are some restrictions. I would like to know how to get around those constraints.

Q) I need to press the shutter release and then press "OK" on the activated camera. I want to finish the process by just pressing the shutter release.

Q) The camera I started up defaults to out-camera. I want to take a picture of myself, so I want to start the in-camera as the default.

How can I get around the above two points?

My environment is as follows.
OS Windows 10 Home
IDE Visual Studio 2019 community
Xamarin.Form(.NET Standard 2.1)
Target Android 9.0(API 28)

Comment: you are going to have to write platform specific code to do this, and expose it via a Custom Renderer or DI

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
First of all, for Android, do you know if there is any sample code somewhere?